# What is .div() method in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I was looking through some code and tried to understand some of the lines of code. I notice it uses .div(integer). Here is the snippet

```
passengers[passenger].insuranceAmountForFlight[flightKey] = insuranceAmount.div(2) + insuranceAmount;
```

what does .div() do here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> what does .div() do here?

Divide.

The contract you're looking at uses [SafeMath.sol](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/math) to protect against integer overflows.

Comment: I think that it is NOT written in Solidity version >= 0.8 because the / operator would behave like the SafeMath .div() with the newest version of Solidity. You do not need .div() in Solidity >= 0.8.

Comment: Ha - good point :-) Would help if I'd written anything in Solidity >=0.8 :-) I'll update the answer make the correction - thanks!